# Java class/interface naming convention

Tags: java, interface, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is standard for Interface naming in java api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939456/what-is-standard-for-interface-naming-in-java-api)

Why is a *able word used for a class such as `Throwable`, since this convention is primarily used for interfaces (e.g., `Cloneable`, `Serializable`, etc.)?

Comment: checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939456/what-is-standard-for-interface-naming-in-java-api

Comment: yup, question is dup. Can someone close it?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is a convention that says that the `able` suffix can only be used for interface. Its just a suffix to denote what the class would be cap`able` of.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the classes which don't appear to follow convention date back to Java 1.0. i.e. before the conventions were established.

E.g. Cloneable is an interface is associated with the method clone() which its says in its Javadoc should be made public, but doesn't include it in its interface.